# multiple attributes not accessible within an angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following html which I can inform you clearly describes each attribute value via a separate "**attachment**" directive. These values are in the attrs list of that directive which is on a modal file upload form.

```
<p>For Testing Purpose: Attachment Type: {{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentType}}</p>
<p>For Testing Purpose: CK ID: {{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentId}}</p>
```

### attachment directive

```
.directive('attachment', ['$modal', function ($modal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        template: '<a class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="open()"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>Attachment</a>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
            scope.open = function () {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: root + 'AccountingModule/modal/attachment/attachment-modal.html',
                    size: 'md',
                    backdrop: true,
                    controller: ['attributes', function (attributes) {
                        var viewModel = this;
                        viewModel.attributes = attributes;
                    }],
                    controllerAs: 'attachCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        attributes: function () { return attrs; }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

When executing a fileupload directive, I'm trying to include both of these attributes so I can send them as parameters via a file upload link. Only the **first** attribute is in the list; the second isn't. If I change the order around, the other attribute is in the list.

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" file-upload 
        attachment-type="{{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentType}}"
        attachment-id="{{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentId}}">
     Upload
</button>
```

directive:

```
console.log('attachment type on file upload directive: ' + attrs.attachmentType)
console.log('attachment id on file upload directive: ' + attrs.attachmentId)
```

### file upload directive

```
.directive('fileUpload', ['$http', '$parse', function ($http, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            //for testing purpose. need to be removed.
            console.log('attachment type on file upload directive: ' + attrs.attachmentType)
            console.log('attachment id on file upload directive: ' + attrs.attachmentId)

            element.bind('click', function () {
                // Create the formdata and get the file
                var file = document.getElementById("inpFile").files[0];
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append('uploadedFile', file);

                ajaxUrl = root + 'FileUpload/upload?' & 'Type=' & attrs.attachmentType & 'ID=' & attrs.attachmentId;
                $http.post(ajaxUrl, formdata, {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
                })
                .success(function (status) {
                    if (status.Succeed) {
                        alert('File Uploaded successfully.');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(status.Err);
                    }
                    });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

**What do I need to do to successfully include both attributes and pass them to the directive where they both will be included in the attribute list?**

Comment: Can you include your directive's code.

Comment: I've just included both directives in an EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're using the attachment directive, but you can make the attributes `attachment-type` and `attachment-id` available in your file upload directive's link function by adding the following `scope` object to your file upload directive:

```
...
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
  attachmentType: '@',
  attachmentId: '@'
},
link: ...
```

Now the file upload directive will be aware of these attributes. This creates an isolate scope on the directive. The `'@'` designates are string, since I'm assuming you're passing strings to those attributes. This should allow you to get rid of that pesky interpolation and just write it like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" file-upload attachment-type="attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentType" attachment-id="attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentId">Upload</button>
```

Please double check the interpolation piece, I have not tested it. Cum grano salis.

In any case, you should now be able to access the values of those two attributes inside your `link` function through `scope.attachmentType` and `scope.attachmentId`. Angular will turn the dashes into camel case for you.

Comment: By isolating the scope in the directive, worked fine to get the two attributes. However, I still needed to use the curly braces for the html designation; otherwise, it came out with a string value of the actual letters for each attribute. Thanks...

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I was wrong. Try using `'='` instead of `'@'` and then skip the interpolation again. That will tell it to treat whatever you pass in as an object, not literally as a string.